# Getting Sum for all first items in each array, all second items in each array etc. ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, array.prototype.map

I am trying to add together an undetermined amount of arrays, but only add or reduce them item by item.

I cannot figure out how to make this work in ES6 javascript.

```js
const arrayList = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [2, 2, 2]
];

const totalRow = arrayList.map((array) => {
  const total = [];
  array.map((number, i) => {
    total[i] = (total[i] == undefined ? 0 : total[i]) + number;
  });
  return total;
});


//Output is just 3 more arrays with no change, as it seems 
//the total variable resets to an empty array with each iteration.

//what i want is this output:
[4, 6, 8]
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried reduce method as well but came up empty

Comment: Use `Array.reduce`.

Comment: The dupe has my answer using `Array.reduce()`, which is perfect for this use-case. `Array.map` is not a right option in this case.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, the other dupe target matches better ...

Comment: @NinaScholz Lemme know the link or edit the links and add it yourself... `:)` Oh wow. You did it already.

Comment: const totalRow = arrayList.map((array) => {
  return Array.isArray(array) ? array.reduce((a, b) => a+b) : array;
});

Comment: also if you only have arrays inside the array just do the array.reduce without the ternary

Comment: thank you @praveenKumar that is perfect

Comment: @leemac33 You are welcome mate! `:D`